# How to deal with Errors which are not following Normal distribution?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, model-selection

I am working on Model Selection problem, where there are two models which are predicting revenues for companies using 2 different formulas. So currently I have Actual revenue values and predicted revenue values. By using this data I have to do model selection. So first of all I have tried with various performance measures of Regression such as Explained Variance Score, Mean Absolute Error, Mean Squared Error , RMSE etc. these were giving weired values. So have removed outliers. It worked. But while checking distribution of errors I come to know that its not following Normal Distribution. So no use of applying above performance measures.

So now I am in confusion that how I should deal with this type of data. How to deal with Errors (Regression) which are not following Normal distribution? Is it okay if I will scale predicted and actual values to normal distribution? Please help… Thanks in advance

Vardhini Kundale

Comment: Non-normal residuals do not have to be problematic for prediction quality. What does it mean to "scale values to normal distribution"? Do you mean transform?

Answer (score 1):

Transforming the data (e.g. scaling or taking the log) to be more normal is perfectly acceptable, you just need to keep in mind that it will affect the interpretation of your model. You would also need to back-transform predicted values to get back to the original scale.

You could also consider modeling the data with some other non-normal distribution, say with a generalized linear model or taking a Bayesian approach.

Comment: okay. thanks.  But problem is that I have only target values ( actual values and predicted values for two models) and based upon that only I have to do model selection.  will Scaling Targets ( Actual as well as Predicted) make errors to follow Normal Distribution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you trying to decide which of the two models is better, or determine whether either of them produce normally distributed errors? If the first, then scaling won't help, that needs to be done before the modeling begins. Maybe take a look at [two sample K-S tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)?

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I will try with non parametric tests